# How to test if point is within rotated ellipsoid?

Tags: geometry, collision-detection, computational-geometry, point

I need to test whether a point (x1,y1,z1) is located within an ellipsoid given by its center (x2,y2,z2), its axes (radii) (a,b,c) and its rotation (e.g. phi1, phi2). How could this be done?

For a small reduction in complexity, it can be assumed that two of the three axes are of identical length.

Comment: Would it be an option to invert the rotation (i.e. apply the inverse rotation (-phi1,-phi2) to (x1,y1,z1) relative to the center of the ellipsoid) and then check containment in the axis-parallel ellipsoid?

Comment: I agree with Codor ,... I would push it even further, create transfrom matrix that transform your point into ellipsoid coordinate system (translation + rotation) and also scales the axises by 1/a,1/b,1/c so if the transformed point (x,y,z) is inside then x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1